# Poetry & Cython - cross-platfrom / build on install

Tags: python, cython, python-poetry, distutils, cythonize

I'm using Poetry v1.4.1 with Cython 3.0.5. My package contains a `.pyx` file that I wish to compile. If I'm using `pyximport` instead of pre-compiling, importing takes a long time. However, if I'm building (with the code below) using `poetry build`, instead of a version- & platform-agnostic wheel file `my_package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`, I get the very specific wheel `my_package-1.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl`.

Is there a way to build the wheel that's fully-agnostic? Maybe cythonize/compile C files at the time of the wheel's installation somehow?

Thanks!

---

### Code:

`pyproject.toml` (partial):

```ini
...
[tool.poetry.build]
generate-setup-file = false
script = 'build.py'

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core", "Cython", "numpy"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

`build.py`:

```py
import os
import shutil
from distutils.core import Distribution
import warnings

if os.environ.get("NO_BUILD", False):
    exit(0)

try:
    from Cython.Build import build_ext, cythonize
    import numpy

    ext_modules = cythonize("my_package/**/*.pyx", output_dir="build", include_path=["dmcommon"],
                            build_dir="build", aliases={'NUMPY': numpy.get_include()})
    dist = Distribution({"ext_modules": ext_modules})
    cmd = build_ext(dist)
    cmd.ensure_finalized()
    cmd.run()

    # Move compiled near origin files.
    for output in cmd.get_outputs():
        relative_extension = os.path.relpath(output, cmd.build_lib)
        relative_output_folder = os.path.dirname(relative_extension)
        os.makedirs(relative_output_folder, exist_ok=True)
        shutil.copyfile(output, relative_extension)
except Exception as ex:
    warnings.warn(f"Failed to build Cython extensions: {ex}")
```